# Android debug setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled what does it mean?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I'm using setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled with a set of fragments, i.e. an activity with A, B, C, D fragments. Upon pressing setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled, it directs to a fragment X.... I really have not idea why this is happening, as I thought I have declare the following in OnCreate() of the activity

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
FragA fragment = new FragA();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frag_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

everything else works fine, except the setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled button... which always directs to fragment X(the settings page actually, i thought it would be directing to frag A!!)

Does anybody have a clue? Big thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can override the behaviour of `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled`. if you want to redirect to the screen where you want to just override the behaviour by following this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 switch (item.getItemId()) {
 case android.R.id.home:
    // do your stuff
    break;
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks!! my code was too long and I totally forgot that i have set transit frag X here....